# Would it be possible to write an addon that allows processing rendering over an Android smartphone in parallel with the desktop computer?

Tags: rendering, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine, add-on

We are engineering students studying management and innovation. 
We would like to use our smartphone’s processing power to reduce the rendering time of a Blender project, a short movie for example (and maybe later other software like Premiere Pro, code compiler, etc…).
Our idea is that a lot of people have a high-end smartphone, but a modest computer.

When rendering, we think that we could use an Android smartphone’s processing power to help reducing rendering time.
There would be an application running on the Android smartphone, and an addon in Blender that changes the way Blender manages frame rendering. Some frames to be processed would be sent to the smartphone’s CPU (or GPU ?). After processing, frames would be sent back to the computer and reassembled to the ones processed by the computer. So there would be a parallel rendering between the computer and the smartphone.

More generally, we would like to be able to render a Blender project using multiple devices and OSes.

Have you heard about similar projects, and do you think it would be feasible (even if it would be hard) ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Transmission between computer and smartphone could be done over network  or cable (for lesser latency)

Comment: **The idea is pointless**, did you ever rendered a scene on any phone? You are wasting energy and you'll need to charge the battery before even 1 single frame is finished. Innovative would be finding a way to **save energy**.

Comment: Android version of Blender https://www.blendernation.com/2015/02/12/using-blender-for-android/ just be aware it has not been updated for 4+ years

Comment: About energy, the phone would be plugged to the PC, so battery charging isn't really a problem. When looking to IGP specs compared to high-end smartphone's GPU, I can see that Adreno 540 and 630 in Snapdragon 820-845 has more or equal GFLOPS (567-737 GFLOPS) compared to most Intel IGPs (Intel HD Graphics 5xx and 6xx) in laptop (300-500 GFLOPS). Maybe it is possible to use raw GPU processing power of the smartphone for rendering ?

Comment: If you still believe that's a thing, there is an android build of ffmpeg to play with - you could encode some raw frames to prores or something and you'll see that this already takes a lot of time. GPU won't drive it anywhere (needs to be implemented) - AMD developers writing code for blender since 2-3 years to support cycles (see blenders history). Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we are investigating about the use of smartphone's GPU through your ideas.